# How to append build jobs into a map?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to implement the code inspired from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40152593/55075) with `<<` operator in the following way:

```
builder = { name, param1, param2 ->
    [job: name, parameters: [string(name: 'Param1', value: param1), string(name: 'Param2', value: param2)], quietPeriod: 2, wait: false]
}
node {
    stage('Tests') {
        def testBuilds = [:]
        testBuilds << build *builder('Test', 'Foo', 'Bar')
        testBuilds << build *builder('Test', 'Foo2', 'Bar2')
        parallel testBuilds
    }
}
```

where I expect to append two jobs into `testBuilds` map in order to run them in parallel.

However when running the job, I've got the following exception error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: build for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:224)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$4.call(Checker.java:241)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:238)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:221)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:221)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:24)
...
```

What would be the correct syntax using the above approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got few problems in your code:

1. Branches description `testBuild` is a *map* (key: value) object, not a *list*. So you cannot left shift (<<) values into it the way you did, such operation is not supported for map
2. Jenkins pipeline *parallel* operation expects map with *closure* as its values.
3. *build* is part of pipeline DSL, not a common Groovy method. It appears it cannot accept arguments this way. While the expression `build *builder(foo, bar)` passes syntax check at first, omitting round brackets is just groovy syntactic sugar. Rewriting this line as `build(*builder(foo, bar))` generates syntax error exception.

All in all, you can rewrite your code in a way like:

```
def builder(name, param1, param2) {
    return build(job: name, parameters: [string(name: 'Param1', value: param1)], [string(name: 'Param2', value: param2)], quietPeriod: 2, wait: false)
}

node {
    stage('Tests') {
        def testBuilds = [:]
        testBuilds['test1'] = { builder('Test', 'Foo', 'Bar') }
        testBuilds['test2'] = { builder('Test', 'Foo2', 'Bar2') }
        parallel testBuilds
    }
}
```